# Testestrone & Nandrolone Injection Safet

Tags: testosterone

I have started a period using *Testosterone* & *Nandrolone* intramuscular injection.

I inject a 100mg/100ml Testosterone & 25mg/100ml Nandrolone together twice a week (Saturdays & Tuesdays)

I want to inject 8 doses of Testosterone (100mg/100ml) and 8 doses of Nandrolone(25mg/100ml) in 4 weeks.

How dangerous is this?

Comment: Before I vote to close this for being off-topic, I have a question.  Since you posted on **this** site, I'll assume you don't have any medical pre-condition that requires the use of steroids.  What is the reason you've decided to take such a drastic and risky course of action?

Comment: I also don't understand the upvote on your question.

Comment: its something natural here (in my city) , so many people use it here and i wanted to try it. it causes to gain muscle very fast. @rrirower

Comment: Anabolic steroids are not "natural" in any city. You should research what you plan to put into your body.

Comment: Ok , I have noticed its dangerous , thank you anyway. but IT IS SOMETHING NATURAL here @rrirower

Comment: @AliSeyfi - If it were natural, you wouldn't need needles to inject it. Most testosterone supplements are synthetic. Just because your body produces testosterone doesn't mean that adding more is natural.

Comment: Off topic but i would take care what you post and where. It didn't take much to find out where you work, others could too. I'm sure no business would condone taking illegal substances

Comment: Note on the use of the word "natural."  One of its meanings is as a synonym for "commonplace," which is what Ali seems to be using.  Since the other 30+ definitions http://www.dictionary.com/browse/natural pertain to non-synthetic concepts, it isn't surprising some people are disputing the matter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## In a word: Very

I am not going to address the issues with self administering IV injections of 125ml in terms of safety (bubbles, infection, needle site issues) but instead look at the effects of both. You are artificially increasing your testosterone level without a medical professionals assessment.

### Testosterone

#### *Mental Health Effects*

Most studies have also found testosterone to be associated with behaviours or personality traits linked with criminality such as antisocial behaviour and alcoholism. Many studies have also been done on the relationship between more general aggressive behaviour/feelings and testosterone. About half the studies have found a relationship and about half no relationship [1]

Studies have also found that testosterone facilitates aggression by modulating vasopressin receptors in the hypothalamus.[2]

Studies conducted have found direct correlation between testosterone and dominance especially among the most violent criminals in prison who had the highest testosterone levels.[3]

#### *Physical Health*

Adverse effects of testosterone supplementation may include increased cardiovascular events (including strokes and heart attacks) and deaths based on three peer-reviewed studies involving men taking testosterone-replacement [4]

In addition, an increase of 30% in deaths and heart attacks in older men has been reported.[5] Recent studies also raise concerns.[6]

Physicians are cautioned about the cancer risk associated with testosterone supplementation.[7]

Adverse effects may also include minor side-effects such as acne and oily skin, as well as, significant hair loss and/or thinning of the hair (which may be prevented with 5-alpha reductase inhibitors). [8]

Exogenous testosterone may also cause suppression of spermatogenesis, leading to, in some cases, infertility. [9]

#### *Benefits*

Testosterone has successfully been taken to enhance muscle development, strength, or endurance. They do so directly by increasing the muscles' protein synthesis. As a result, muscle fibers become larger and repair faster than the average person's.

### Nandrolone

Not much has been established about this drug in terms of side effect studies on a large scale but i'll summarise what I found.

#### *Physical Effects*

Abuse can cause erectile dysfunction and cardiovascular damage, as well as several ailments resulting from the drug's effect of lowering levels of luteinizing hormone through negative feedback. Erectile dysfunction is attributed to the weaker action of dihydronandrolone in the penis since dihydrotestosterone is a known sexual modulator.

There is a study here which may provide more information: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15076791

Essentially the findings were that the administration of 200 mg. of Nandrolone (intramuscularly) for 8 weeks significantly increased body mass, whereas fat mass, bone mineral content, bone mineral density were unaffected. These data indicate that the changes can be attributed to an increase of muscle mass.

#### Summary

To summarise, tests show that using both drugs can enhance your body's recovery and paired with the right training can boost muscle growth. Is it worth it? Unlikely. A well rounded diet with correct levels of protean and a heavy gym routine will get you the same, clean, results. IF you want evidence, google John Cena; John has tested clear on every single drug test over his entire life.

[1] Wright J, Ellis L, Beaver K (2009). Handbook of crime correlates. San Diego: Academic Press. pp. 208–210. ISBN 0-12-373612-9.

[2] Delville, Y.; Mansour, K. M.; Ferris, C. F. (1996-07-01). "Testosterone facilitates aggression by modulating vasopressin receptors in the hypothalamus". Physiology & Behavior 60 (1): 25–29. doi:10.1016/0031-9384(95)02246-5. ISSN 0031-9384. PMID 8804638.

[3] Archer J (2006). "Testosterone and human aggression: an evaluation of the challenge hypothesis" (PDF). Neuroscience and Biobehavioral Reviews 30 (3): 319–45. doi:10.1016/j.neubiorev.2004.12.007.

[4] Finkle WD, Greenland S, Ridgeway GK, Adams JL, Frasco MA, Cook MB, Fraumeni JF, Hoover RN (January 2014). "Increased risk of non-fatal myocardial infarction following testosterone therapy prescription in men" (PDF). PLOS ONE 9 (1): e85805. doi:10.1371/journal.pone.0085805. PMC 3905977. PMID 24489673.

[5] Vigen R, O'Donnell CI, Barón AE, Grunwald GK, Maddox TM, Bradley SM, Barqawi A, Woning G, Wierman ME, Plomondon ME, Rumsfeld JS, Ho PM (Nov 2013). "Association of testosterone therapy with mortality, myocardial infarction, and stroke in men with low testosterone levels". JAMA 310 (17): 1829–36. doi:10.1001/jama.2013.280386. PMID 24193080.

[6] "Testosterone Products: Drug Safety Communication – FDA Investigating Risk of Cardiovascular Events". FDA. January 31, 2014. Retrieved February 3, 2014.

[7] Gaylis FD, Lin DW, Ignatoff JM, Amling CL, Tutrone RF, Cosgrove DJ (Aug 2005). "Prostate cancer in men using testosterone supplementation". The Journal of Urology 174 (2): 534–8; discussion 538. doi:10.1097/01.ju.0000165166.36280.60. PMID 16006887.

[8] "Therapeutic Advances in Drug Safety", Adverse effects of testosterone replacement therapy: an update on the evidence and controversy, October 2004

[9] "Contraceptive efficacy of testosterone-induced azoospermia in normal men. World Health Organization Task Force on methods for the regulation of male fertility". Lancet 336 (8721): 955–9. Oct 1990. doi:10.1016/0140-6736(90)92416-F. PMID 1977002.